# Removing all occurrences of an element within an array (setting it to null)

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to set all occurrences of an element to an array if it is found via a linear search. Let's say the array is as follows:

```
[Steve, Steve, John, Mike, Gary, Bob, Susan, Mike, Sarah]
```

Let say if I want to set all occurrences of Mike to null. I've tried the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < iTMembers.length; i++) {
    if (iTMembers[i].equals(memberName)) {
        iTMembers[i] = null;
        break;                              
    }               
}
```

The problem however is that it only sets one Mike (String Literal Element) to null and the other one is still present. What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: if you remove break you get a null pointer exception.

Comment: Removing break gives a nullPointer Exception. I don't think Exception Handling would work here correct?

Comment: Getting NPE (NullPointerException) suggests that you are ending up with `null[index]` or `null.member`. Possibly you have `null` somewhere inside your array like `{Steve, Steve, John, null, ..., }`. Try to print each `iTMembers[i]` before you enter `if`.

Comment: I'll try that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the `break;` line because it breaks your loop after the first replacement.
2. Change

   ```
   if (iTMembers[i].equals(memberName))
   ```

   to

   ```
   if (memberName.equals(iTMembers[i]))
   ```

   because if `iTMembers[i]` is `null`, you want a `false` result, not a `NullPointerException`.